# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE cannot be resolved or is not a field for google threadsample

Tags: android, multithreading, view, threadpool, android-view

I have import the threadsample code from https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html,
but I got errors after I import it.

They are : 
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE cannot be resolved or is not a field
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION cannot be resolved or is not a field

The project minSdkVersion=11 and targetSdkVersion=17, and I have already setup the support.v4 with it.

Does anyone have the same problem? How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.
[image: Screen capture]

Comment: plz post your class codes

Comment: well, actually I just import the whole project from the link, i have changed nothing in code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a mistake `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` is included in `API >= 14` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` is included in `API >= 16`
So you need minSdk=14. See the document at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE.
Need to change the project build target to Android 4.0 to get rid of the errors.

Comment: Help, although I changed the API level to 16, after clean and refresh, the problem still exists.

Comment: Right click your project --> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties and then rebuild.

Comment: What is your project build target?

Comment: Right click your project --> Properties --> Android --> Check Android 4.2 and then OK